Consider the quadratic form $Q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^{2}+z^{2}+xy+yz+zx$.

Consider the quadratic form $Q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^{2}+z^{2}+xy+yz+zx$.Which of the following statements are true?1.There exists non-zero $u\in\Bbb Q^3$ s.t. $Q(u)=0$.2.There exists non-zero $u\in\Bbb R^3$ s.t. $Q(u)=0$.3.There exists non-zero $u\in\Bbb C^3$ s.t. $Q(u)=0$.4.The real symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix of this quadratic form is invertible.

As matrix of the quadratic form with respect to standard basis is ,$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&1&{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$So the characteristic polynomial of the above matrix is given by $C_A(x)=x^3-3x^2+\frac{9}{4}x-\frac{1}{2}$.
So the spectrum of A is given by {2,$\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{1}{2}$}.Therefore A is invertible and positive definite hence option(1) and (2) are incorrect.
Now for option(3) I could not find any non-zero $u\in\Bbb C^3$ s.t. $Q(u)=0$.(Option (3) is given correct)

one mistake, the impossibility of a real null vector, your statement (2), is not caused by the matrix being invertible. Rather that it is positive definite. Cultural:  taking $(x,y,z)$  as all integer triples, the resulting represented integers are all natural numbers not of the form $4^k (16n+14)$

Example, instead of your form, take $x^2 + y^2 - z^2.$  The matrix that goes with this is invertible but indefinite, and it is easy to find rational vectors where this  form becomes zero, namely Pythagorean triples

@WillJagy I parsed "option (1) and (2) are incorrect" as a consequence of "the spectrum of $A$ is given by $\left{2, \frac12, \frac12\right}$ [whose elements are all positive]", not of "$A$ is invertible".

@TravisWillse I see what you mean; could be.

if you are familiar with things like elementary symmetric functions or Newton's Identities, you should be able to guess (3.) by considering e.g. a polynomial $p(z) = (z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)(z-\lambda_3) = z^3 - 1$.  Setting the coefficient for $z^2$ to zero ensures that $\sum_k \lambda_k =0$ and then setting the next coefficient (for $z$) to zero ensures $\sum_k \lambda_k^2 =0$ which implies the 2nd elementary symmetric sum is zero -- check $ \big(\sum_k \lambda_k\big)^2 = 0$

@user8675309 sorry sir, i am not familiar but definitely i will search for.

Yes, your work so far is correct.
Hint As for (3), impose $z = 0$, so that we're looking for nonzero solutions of
$$x^2 + x y + y^2 = 0.$$
One option for proceeding is multiplying by $x - y$, giving
$$x^3 - y^3 = 0 ,$$ being sure to avoid the introduced solutions with $x = y$.

 So $y = e^{\pm \frac{2\pi i}3} x$, and we can take, e.g., $u = (1, e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}, 0)$.

